# How to show different JointJS blocks on tabs changing

Tags: javascript, tabs, jointjs

Is JointJS support tabs or can I integrate tabs quickly on JointJS to show different block collections on tabs changing? Better with example, please! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**JointJS** gives you **graph**(s) represented on **paper**(s) with some elements

so create:

- more different joint.dia.Paper with connected joint.dia.Graph
- create tabs for example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp use appropriate paper on each tab

you can do both:

- have as many graphs as tabs
- same graph with different paper representation on each tab